# Oven temperature when increase bread recipe?

Tags: bread, temperature, oven

I increased my bread recipe by 50% to get a larger loaf. I used the oven temp for the original (smaller) loaves I baked consistently with success in the past.After the same baking time the center bread temp was too low (i.e., it was not done on inside). Did I need to increase oven temp too?And if s, is there a formula to increase temps? (I.e., a percentage in relation to recipe/flour increase?). 
Thank you.

Comment: What temperature are we talking about?

Answer (score 6):

You need to increase *something* and time is the easiest:  for 50% more weight add 50% more time is the rule of thumb for an increase up to 100%.

You can also increase both temperature *and* time but then you should halve each so 25% hotter and 25% longer.

<sub>**Note:** This works up to an increase of 100%. Larger than that, volume calculations come into place too.</sub>

Comment: And the larger the loaf, the more important is “falling heat”, i.e. decreasing the oven temperature during baking.

Answer (score 0):

Don't increase temperature. Increase the time by proportion